# Chrome console API for getting HTTP Response code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How does one query for the website's HTTP response code (200, 500, 404, etc) in Chrome's Javascript Console? Since I'm using Chrome in headless mode from command line, I don't have access to the GUI DevTools window. Preferably,

I'd like to know the name of the Javascript API that allows me to query for other HTTP response details from Chrome's Javascript console. I also don't want to install additional extensions to make this work.

Comment: In chrome developer tools you can switch to the network tab, from there you can check for any response codes that you website is generating.

Comment: perhaps I don't understand the limitations of headless chrome, but can you use the traditional `fetch` api? mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty unclear but I'll try my best.

If you need to make requests from the console, you can use the built in javascript APIs [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). If you need to check the `HTTP` status of the current loaded page, you can `fetch` `location.href` and log the results. This is technically a different request, but it is the **only** way to get this information. Here is an example using `XMLHttpRequest` (for normal code I would recommend `fetch` but `XMLHttpRequest` will probably work better in the console):

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('get', 'yoururl.com');
req.send();
req.status; //in the console this will automatically log the request status
```

Depending on where you're opening the console from and what kind of requests you're making, you may run into CORS errors.

If you need to monitor HTTP requests that happen during an application's lifecycle while you are inspecting, you can use chromes `monitorEvents` utility by entering `monitorEvents(XHMLHttpRequests, 'readystatechange')` directly into the console. After entering this code, each complete `XHMLHttpRequest` will be logged to the console. Note that this is only available in the Chrome console and is not present in any other javascript environment.

If neither of these suits your needs then I'm not sure you have any other options.

Comment: How do you know that having an extra XHR is the only way? It seems to me that not having a proper API for DevTools functionalities is quite silly.

Comment: Because I read [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/). Only the console itself actually has commands, no other devtools tab has any sort of API. I agree it's silly but I'm not sure what else to tell you, as far as I can tell based on all available information the above is the only way to get the information you want. Can I ask why this doesn't work? What specific reason are trying to get the page status code from a headless chrome instance? There may be some other viable solution